# What is a recommended way to optimize my app given this server log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

Here is my server log for loading my `Dashboard#Index` action:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-27 03:26:56 -0500
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  FamilyTree Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  ReadMark Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "read_marks".* FROM "read_marks"  WHERE "read_marks"."user_id" = $1 AND "read_marks"."readable_type" = 'PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity' AND "read_marks"."readable_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "read_marks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Membership Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 3  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_profile_box.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Node Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."family_tree_id" = $1 AND "nodes"."is_comment" IS NULL  [["family_tree_id", 1]]
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "memberships"."family_tree_id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC  [["family_tree_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_upload.html.erb (13.2ms)
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Video Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "videos".* FROM "videos"  WHERE "videos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (34.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  Participant Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants"  WHERE "participants"."video_id" = $1  [["video_id", 6]]
  Rendered shared/_box.html.erb (14247.4ms)
  Comment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."node_id" = $1  [["node_id", 1]]
  NodeComment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "node_comments".* FROM "node_comments"  WHERE "node_comments"."node_id" = $1  [["node_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Best_in_place] :type is deprecated in favor of :as . (called from best_in_place_deprecated_options at /Users/marcgayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@kordli/bundler/gems/best_in_place-0a0f62e19a8b/lib/best_in_place/helper.rb:152)
  Rendered shared/_comments.html.erb (23.9ms)
  Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14295.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_search.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_edit.html.erb (12.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_edit_account_popup.html.erb (13.5ms)
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" LEFT JOIN read_marks as read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type  = 'PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity'
                                   AND read_marks.readable_id    = activities.id
                                   AND read_marks.user_id        = 1
                                   AND read_marks.timestamp     >= activities.created_at WHERE "activities"."owner_id" = 1 AND (read_marks.id IS NULL)
  Notification Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" LEFT JOIN read_marks as read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type  = 'PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity'
                                   AND read_marks.readable_id    = activities.id
                                   AND read_marks.user_id        = 1
                                   AND read_marks.timestamp     >= activities.created_at WHERE "activities"."owner_id" = 1 AND (read_marks.id IS NULL)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_destroy.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/node/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/participant/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/participant/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_destroy.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_notifications.html.erb (127.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_profile.html.erb (143.7ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_edit.html.erb (15.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_edit_account_popup.html.erb (16.0ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "memberships"."family_tree_id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC  [["family_tree_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_upload_video_popup.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (173.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14510ms (Views: 14448.1ms | ActiveRecord: 55.1ms)
```

I am tempted to do ActiveRecord optimizations, using eager loading and all this jazz....but given the difference in times between the `Views` time and `ActiveRecord` time, that approach seems silly.

This is my `Dashboard#Index` Controller:

```
  def index
    @family_tree = current_user.family_tree
    @nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes(:comments)
    @video = Video.new
    @videos = Video.all.where(:is_complete => true)
    @node = current_user.nodes.new
    @memberships = current_user.memberships.limit(3)    

    if params[:search]
      @nodes = Node.node_search(params[:search])
    else
      @videos = Video.all.order('created_at DESC')
      # flash[:notice] = "No results found"
    end
  end
```

This is my `Dashboard/index.html.erb`:

```
<% if !resource.errors.messages.empty? %>
    <!-- <div><%#= resource.errors.inspect %></div> -->
    <div><%= devise_error_messages2! %></div>
<% end %>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">
  <% if current_user.sign_in_count == 1 %>
    <div class="hidden" id="new-user"></div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Profile -->
                <%= render "shared/profile_box" %>
                <!-- // Profile -->
            </div> <!-- //row -->
      <!-- Video -->
      <div id="video">
          <!-- Box Add -->
          <div class="box add-video" data-popup="add-video-step-1" data-step="3" data-intro="To upload a video simply click in this box or the upload a video button in the main bar.">
                        <a class="upload popupbox" href="#" data-popup="add-video-step-1">
              <%= image_tag("buttons/upload-video.gif")%>
                        </a>
          </div>
          <!-- Box -->
          <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
                <!-- Upload Video Comment Popup -->
           <%= render partial: "shared/upload", locals: {node: node} %>

          <div class="box">
              <%= render partial: "shared/box", locals: {node: node} %>

              <%= render partial: "shared/comments", locals: {node: node} %>
          </div>
          <% end %> <!-- node -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rather than cluttering the question with code from my partials, I figured I would just leave it be and if you guys request it, I will add them later.

I suspect that there are one or two things I can do to drastically reduce that views render time. It is ridiculously high.

I am also using Turbolinks, but no caching.

Would Russian Doll caching be recommended here, given my use of Turbolinks? Also is my analysis correct, i.e. that I am better served focusing on the view rendering than AR queries? Or should I go ahead and optimize those too?

I don't necessarily need ABSOLUTE 100% efficiency, I just don't want a load time of 14+ seconds. That seems crazy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the biggest impact change I had was getting rid of the N+1 problem, which I did with this eager loading assignment:

`@nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes(:comments => :user)`

These are the results. The original loading time was this:

`Completed 200 OK in 14510ms (Views: 14448.1ms | ActiveRecord: 55.1ms)`

This is a random sample of 3 homepage refreshes now:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1125ms (Views: 1093.1ms | ActiveRecord: 24.6ms)

Completed 200 OK in 994ms (Views: 963.3ms | ActiveRecord: 23.8ms)

Completed 200 OK in 1428ms (Views: 1375.8ms | ActiveRecord: 47.5ms)
```

**Average**

```
Completed 200 OK in 1182.3ms (Views: 1144.07ms | ActiveRecord: 31.97ms)
```

**Improvement**

```
Completed: 91% improvement overall

Views: 92.1% improvement

ActiveRecord: 41.97% improvement.
```

Thanks to Fer in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26625454/91970 - for providing clarity with how to tackle this.