# How do I eager load two levels of associations in 1 call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have `FamilyTree, Node, Comment, & User` models.

The relationship is like this:

`FamilyTree`

```
class FamilyTree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nodes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`Node`

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`Comment`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :node
end
```

`User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :family_tree, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
end
```

`Membership ## This is just to store the user memberships on various family_trees`

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :user      
end
```

In my `Dashboard#IndexController` where I am using this, I have:

```
  def index
    @family_tree = current_user.family_tree
    @nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes(:comments)
    @node = current_user.nodes.new
    @memberships = current_user.memberships.limit(3)    
  end
```

When I am trying to optimize my app with the Bullet gem, I get this message:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Comment => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:user]
N+1 Query method call stack
```

My `_comments` partial that is generating this N+1 issue is called like this - in my `views/dashboard/index.html.erb`:

```
      <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
          <%= render partial: "shared/comments", locals: {node: node} %>
      <% end %> <!-- node -->
```

This is where the n+1 offending queries occur, around these lines in my `_comments` partial.

```
<% node.comments.each do |comment| %>
     <li class="clearfix">
         <a class="avatar" href="#">
             <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.url)%>
```

So it seems the solution is to optimize my controller call, but I am not quite sure how to do 2-levels of association. I tried this:

```
@nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes(:comments).includes(:user)
```

But that doesn't seem to get rid of the N+1 query problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: @User089247 I tried your suggestion, and I got this error: `undefined method includes' for #<FamilyTree:0x007fe9d067d0b0>` But @Fer's answer works, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass a hash to the `includes`

```
@nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes(:comments => :user)
```